# brightness settings on Ubuntu 11.10 64bit, Hardware Dell 1555 with ATI Mobility Radeon HD4570

Tags: 11.10, display, dell, brightness

My laptop Dell studio 1555 has Ubuntu 11.10.
At every boot I have to set the brightness level as it gets reset to 100%.
Could you please help me out to find a way not to change it every time?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have found that disabling the "Varibright" option under power management in the AMD Control Center fixes the brightness problem.  I've never really measured what effect turning it off has on batter life, but I still get great battery life so I'm thinking the effect is minimal.